# UI is not being updated on the main thread when performing segue

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to add an image to another imageView.image which is located in another view controller by performing/preparing for segue, however when I try to do the variables in the bg thread and then hop to the main thread to update it, it doesn't work. But if I remove the dispatch thing, then it works. Here's the code:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    SwiftSpinner.show(progress: 0.2, title: "Loading full image, please wait...")
    let vc = segue.destination as! PhotoViewController
    let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell) {
            let url = URL(string: self.images[indexPath.row].rawURL)
            let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url!)
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData as! Data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                vc.image = image!
                vc.mainImage = image!
                vc.photographerName = self.images[(indexPath.row)].photographerName
                SwiftSpinner.hide()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's something to do with you trying to access the collection view in the background thread, but thats the least of your worries with this approach. You should instead pass in the URL to the PhotoViewController and it should be that downloading the image, it shouldn't be done in the prepareForSegue method.

Comment: Alright thanks, but may I ask why does it work if I remove DispatchQueue.global and DispatchQueue.main.async?

Comment: Probably because you are accessing the collectionView on the main thread. See my answer above ;)

Comment: Alright, used Nuke and it worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working! But honestly, think about refactoring your prepareForSegue method, you shouldn't be doing image loading in there, it's simply so you can set properties on the VC you are about to present, it should be the presented VC's responsibility to initiate downloading the image it's going to show. If you want to reuse the PhotoViewController you will have to repeat this image download code every time you want to use it, but if you move the download code into the VC then it makes it a lot more reusable and easy to maintain.

Comment: Yeah, still new to Swift. Thakn you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) for things like this. It takes all that junk and turns it into:

```
 . . .
let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
let url = URL(string: self.images[indexPath.row].rawURL)
vc.imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
 . . .
```

But yeah. @dlbuckley is right. Don't do that stuff in prepareForSegue if you don't do something like KingFisher.

Comment: Yes. I used Nuke to load the image and it worked. Thanks :)